# Cursor moving off line Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am currently completing a programming task in Python using the Turtle module, I have the following code:

```
from turtle import *
number_of_shapes = 4
for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
    size = shape * 20
    for sides in range(4):
        forward(size + 10)
        right(90)
penup()
forward(size + 10)
left(90)
forward(size + 30)
right(90)
pendown()
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

However, I want the turtle to stop here:

[image]

I've tried changing all the figures but can't seem to find the value that relates to the turtle, can anyone assist?

Comment: Don't use salutations: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have some fun by trying a different approach.  This will draw the same figure and leave the turtle where you want it.  But, it will minimize turtle motion (no redrawing over the same line), at the expense of slightly more code, and never lift the pen off the paper while drawing:

```
from turtle import *

NUMBER_OF_SHAPES = 4

angle = 90
magnitude = -1
shape = NUMBER_OF_SHAPES

for _ in range(2):
    right(angle)
    forward(shape * 20 + 10)

    for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_SHAPES - 1):
        right(angle)
        forward((2 * shape + magnitude + 1) * 20)

        shape += magnitude
        angle = -angle

    magnitude = -magnitude

    right(angle)
    forward(shape * 20 + 10)

done()
```

The idea is that instead of viewing/implementing this as a set of multiple squares, view/implement it as two zig zag lines of varying size that meet up at their ends.

[image]

> Is it possible to produce the same output with one loop?

One way would be to abandon *drawing* and switch to *stamping* by making the turtle itself the square.  This would eliminate the loop used to draw the square and only require one loop to size, stamp, and move the square:

```
from turtle import *

NUMBER_OF_SHAPES = 4
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

shape('square')
fillcolor('white')
penup()

for n in range(1, NUMBER_OF_SHAPES + 1):
    size = n * 20 + 10
    goto(xcor() + size/2, ycor() + size/2)
    shapesize(size / CURSOR_SIZE)
    stamp()
    goto(xcor() + size/2, ycor() + size/2)

shapesize(1)
shape('classic')
fillcolor('black')
done()
```

This produces the same visible result but via a completely different means that has its own rules and contraints:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to produce the same output with one loop?

Comment: @APStevens, both your and my examples use two loops to draw the figure.  I've added an alternate approach to my answer that draws the figure in a single loop via stamping.

Answer (score 0):

You just messed up the last part here is how to do it:

```
from turtle import *
number_of_shapes = 4
a=5
for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes+1):
    size = shape * 20
    for sides in range(a):
        forward(size + 10)
        right(90)
    right(180)
    a=6
```

If you need anything just ask:)

Comment: Your solution does work but it changes the output, I need the output to remain the same. It's only the position of the turtle that needs to change.

Comment: I changed some of the code and now its working!